# jQuery 1.5.2 detach = error

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the jQuery `detach()` function. See the [Example page](http://jsfiddle.net/kVWJ5/). 
The chrome throws this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replaced'`.
and Firefox/Firebug this one:
'c.replace is not a function' 
in the jQuery File

The HTML code:

```
<nav class="menu center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-link="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Z4</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
```

```
<div  id="RTMPClient"><p>text</p></div>
        </section>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
$(".menu").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    var dataValue = $(this).data("link");
    var contentDiv = $(".flash");
    var flash = $(contentDiv).find("#RTMPClient");
    if (dataValue=='home') {
        contentDiv.prepend(flash);
    } else {
       contentDiv.detach(flash);
    }

});
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this error?

Comment: Although live examples are a great *adjunct* to a question, always include all of the relevant code *in the question itself*. There are a couple of reasons for this. First, people shouldn't have to follow the link to help you. Second, and probably more importantly, external links can be changed, moved, or removed, making the question useless. StackOverflow is meant to stand alone, and to be useful not only to the person asking the question, but to people with largely the same question in the future.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You are right. @Jason McCreary: I shortened the code.so, path is a relict from the original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how [`.detach()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/detach) works..

the parameter it takes is a selector and not an element. And that selector will filter the original selection (*not search inside it*)

for example

```
$('.someclass').detach('.otherclass')
```

will detach the elements that have both `someclass` and `otherclass` applied.
It **not** detach the elements that have `otherclass` applied that are inside some other element with class `someclass`.

You likely want to do

```
flash.detach();
```

but you should save that to a variable if you want to re-insert it a later time.

otherwise just use `flash.remove()`

Comment: Thanks. i found the solution for few seconds. But you were right, i thought the function get an element...